# Spotify iOS SDK 1.0.2 - playing albums available offline without internet connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, spotify

is there a way to use the the latest spotify SDK (https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk) to access my offline music without having to connect to the internet?

Although offline is "supported" this partially works in the demo. The user needs to get a new token  (App Remote SDK) which requires internet connection.

This means once the "remote connection" to the spotify app disconnects

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    if (self.appRemote.isConnected) {
        [self.appRemote disconnect];
    }
}
```

getting a new token requires internet access:

```
if (self.appRemote.connectionParameters.accessToken) {
   [self.appRemote connect];
}
```

what am i doing wrong? If offline mode is supported, i expect to access offline music without any internet access, right?